# How to encrypt the data using hibernate, without annotation.?

Tags: hibernate

How can encrypt the data base fields when using the hibernate?

We have developed the product some of the clients are using that application Some clients is asking about the data base encryption Is there any possible to encrypt the data in application level with out more changes in the code.

Please give me the suggestion as soon as possible.

Comment: PrePersist PostUpdate lifecycle events? You can configure them wihtout annotations (xml), but not without code changes

Comment: First thing, you look up the lifecycle event definition and configuration options - jpa spec and hibernate docs as well as a buch of posts here on SO have this info. Then you try and should you fail you ask a more to-the-point question. Right now, it's so broadly stated that I wouldnt know where to begin

Comment: i have a bean:
 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }

 /**
  * @param message
  *            the message to set
  */
 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }

i want to encrypt the message..??
now how can i do that??